# IStringLocalizer create resx files

Tags: internationalization, blazor, translation, .net-7.0

I want to add some translations to my `Blazor` web application. Upon research I found a great way to do this is using `IStringLocalizer` like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.localization.istringlocalizer?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0).

However I find it hard to manually create the `*.resx` files. I mean every class has a `localizer` instance via

```
@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.IStringLocalizer<MyPage> _localizer
```

and text is translated like this

```
@_localizer["This is a translated text."]
```

Now is there a way to execute a command in `Developer Command Prompt` with a given language in order to automatically create translation files for all `localizer` instances, so files like *Resources\MyPage.en.resx* and *Resources\MyPage.de.resx* and so on are created and can be translated?